# Error in eval(predvars, data, env): object 'V1' not found

Tags: r, linear-regression, read.table

I'm trying to use the linear regression's tools:

```
data=read.table("http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~winner/data/pgalpga2008.dat",  check.names=FALSE)
```

Then I have to select only female golfers so I did:

```
datF <- subset(data, V3==1, select=1:2)
```

Where V3 is the label of the third column. Now I should apply the linear regression method so I did:

```
datF.lm=lm(V1~V2)
```

Where V1 and V2 are the label of the other two column but I came through this error and I can't understand why.

Comment: `datF.lm <- lm(V1~V2, data = datF)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as slava-kohut states, the `lm()` function requires a reference to the dataframe as one of its arguments. If you don't specify `data = datF`, `lm()` doesn't know where to look for the variables V1 and V2.